# Overriding the Python help() function behaviour

Tags: python

I've created a Python proxy class that calls methods on a remote object.  I've used a closure to override the **doc** attribute on my dynamically created methods so that

```
help(obj.method)
```

gives me the help on my remote object method.  I then decided that I wanted to do the same thing for the object attributes.  I have in my class something like:

```
class Proxy:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Do stuff to get remote attribute
```

Now when calling code like this:

```
help(obj.attribute)
```

I of course get the doc string of the queried value type (string, int or whatever was returned).

The only way I can think to avoid this is to get a stack dump inside `__getattr__()`, identify and look for the help() call, and conditionally return object/class instead of the remotely queried value.
This is obviously non-ideal because there are quite a few ways one could specify the same thing, however it would help me from the command-line which is the most likely place I am to use this, so perhaps better than nothing.

Is there a better way?

Comment: That is also the case with non-`getattr` attributes. Only for functions/modules/classes it uses the docstring, since that docstring is *attached* to the function. For instance `help(0.real)` will also give you the page of `int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think you meant `help(int(0).real)`, but I got the idea.